# What commands are used to install software on AIX?

Tags: software-installation, aix

Starting with AIX5.0 (the beta AIX5 during Project Montery) two additional methods (RPM and ISMP) of unpacking aka installing software were added.

What commands can be used to install the different types of packaging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most generic method - and the one that resolves the "lower layer" or differences in the different formats is: **smit install**

`smit install` - as part of smit takes you through a number of dialogs to help with selections. Ultimately this calls the program `/usr/sbin/geninstall`

So the next aspect of this question is: what does `geninstall` call?

---

### Legacy INSTALLP

(aka BFF - backup file format)

The installp/bff format uses the command `installp`.
`installp` is simple to use from the command line:
`installp` is also a package manager in that it can also resolve and install dependencies - when available in the /software/repository/directory
The following commands demonstrate some common actions with *LPP*/*installp*/*BFF* packaging.

To install **some.fileset.name** from /software/repository/directory while also finding and installing dependancies - as well as increase filesystems size should that be necessary

- installp -d /software/repository/directory -agX some.fileset.name
  -d: directory with software package/packages in BFF format
  -a: apply
  -g: resolve and apply dependencies, if any
  -X: increase target filesystem size, if needed

List software in repository

- installp -d /software/repository/directory -L
  -d: directory with software package/packages in BFF format
  -L: List LPP packages in directory

Regenerate the TOC in /software/repository/directory

- inutoc /software/repository/directory
  Uninstall some.fileset.name
- installp -ug some.fileset.name
  -u: uninstall argument(s)
  -g: uninstall, recursively, software that depends on some.fileset.name

Listing/verification of already installed packages

- lslpp -L
  List installed LPP packages - do not distinguish between root, usr or shared components
- lslpp -l
  List installed LPP packages - include the distinct root, usr and/or shared components
- lppck -v some.fileset.name
  -v: verify contents of
  Verify some.fileset.name integrity
- lslpp -h some.fileset.name
  -h: history of
  List the installation history (install dates) of current and previous versions of some.fileset.name
  -w: where is
- lslpp -w /some/file/name
  Identify the fileset that contains /some/file/name

---

### RPM - RedHat Package Manager

`rpm on AIX` is standard rpm - see any Linux guide for instructions on how to use it. Note that the version of RPM installed is 'ancient'. Some  options you expect may be missing.

```
michael@x071:[/usr/sbin]rpm --version
RPM version 3.0.5
```

`/usr/bin/rpm` is installed by default, and is part of the fileset named
**rpm.rte**

```
michael@x071:[/usr/sbin]lslpp -w /usr/bin/rpm
  File                                        Fileset               Type
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/bin/rpm                                rpm.rte               File
```

Starting with AIX 7.2 (which I do not have access to right now) has rpm version 4, and `yum` is also included to help with *RPM dependency hell*

---

### ISMP

InstallShield Multi Platform

I have never tried to install ISMP from the command-line, so no quick summary here. The main 'user' of this packaging method has been '3rd-party' VAR and software vendors. IBM software group has also been a frequent user - more in the past (e.g., db2v6 or v7, and the initial versions of apache-1 and httpd-2).

- a quick description can be found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/install/ismp_installation.html (Thanks Jeff Schaller, for the link, updated in Oct 2020 to point at AIX 7.2 docs.)
- The key point seems to be that `installp` and `RPM` never have user interaction while ISMP may (read, probably needs a response file to be hands free)

---

### Personal Notes

- For me personally, ISMP is a 'historical note', as I see it less and less (not even IBM software group seems to use it anymore). Further, RPM is something I prefer to avoid on AIX. Not because I dislike RPM - but because the common flaw (**imho**) is that RPM packages do not know what installp has installed (and v.v.) and RPM overwrites the contents of other installp packages without warning or thereafter remove bits without warning. This knife cuts two ways: 'the new' gets broken when 'the old' has an update applied. In short - mix -> and make a murphy day!
- personally, in 2001 I thought three different installers was a great idea. And `geninstall` to control them all. Experience with troubleshooting things suddenly gone wrong have taught me otherwise!

Comment: removing guesswork - yes on ISMP: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.install/ismp_installation.htm

Comment: nice post, why do you call installp legacy? it is still majorly used for all type of system specific packages

Comment: legacy - maybe a poor choice - maybe OEM was better. FYI, I package OSS for AIX - and use installp as format.