# How do you install NodeJS on AIX?

Tags: package-management, aix

I am currently running a server running AIX 7.1 and was wondering how I install NodeJS.

I cannot seem to find the `apt-get` package manager, nor the `yum` package manager? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: By the way, Starting with AIX 7.2 has rpm version 4, and yum is also included to help with RPM dependency hell

Answer (score 0):

AIX isn't Linux, it is a commerial UNIX by IBM. And it probably don't have dpkg (thus apt). AIX does have `rpm` but no `yum` until 7.2.

However, Node.JS download [page](https://nodejs.org/en/download) has an installer for [AIX on Power Systems](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.0/node-v14.18.0-aix-ppc64.tar.gz). Also, you can always build from [source](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.0/node-v14.18.0.tar.gz).

Comment: What commands would I use to execute this, would it be a `tar -xzvf node-v14.18.0-aix-ppc64.tar.gz`? Once I have extracted all files how do I run them to install? Sorry, I am new to all of this.

Comment: I don't know about much AIX. `smitty install` might work. Also read [this] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325701/what-commands-are-used-to-install-software-on-aix). If nothing works, decompress the tarball and copy the directories to root directory (contents of `bin` in `/bin` and such) or `/usr/local/` (if such thing exists in AIX).